# Tshark delay time in inialization

Tags: python, tshark

I try to sniff packets using tshark 1.10.0.
It seems that it has some delay from the moment I run the command to the moment it actually starts printing the packets. 
When I run Wireshark, the packets are seen but they're not seen in tshark.
Sleeping for some seconds, sometimes solve the problem, but it's not stable enough.

Just to make things clear, I run tshark with python's `subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` and read the packets from it. 
The tshark is initialized and then I start sending packets to the machine.

The question is: does tshark 1.10.0 have delay time until it starts capturing and how can I measure this delay?

Comment: It's probably just output buffering.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean in output buffering? tshark's or python's? I use tshark flush output flag (```-l```).

Comment: I meant tshark's, but `-l` should solve that.

Comment: It might take a little time to initialize the packet filter, but that should be the same with Wireshark. They both use the same code to get packets, they only differ in how they display them (GUI vs terminal).